# Error deploying react app site to root folder on cPanel?

Tags: reactjs, .htaccess, syntax-error, cpanel

so im in a issue that i cant figure it out... i have a site deployed an **working** in ex: *[www.mydomain.com/v1/](http://www.mydomain.com/v1/)* the V1 folder was my testing folder during the implementation since de " *www.mydomain.com*" was a simple html file with the under construction information...

now im trying to deploy it to runs in a root folder / domain *[www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com)*

in CPANEL i have : [image: CPANEL - NODE.JS]

In Application root i have to set a folder, because it doesn't allow to set on root folder : (Directory "public_html" not allowed)

during the implementation i have in the field **Application URL** /V1/ (*mydomain.com/v1/*)

since i want to use only mydomain.com in this new application i left the fiel **Application URL** empty.

in my folder **public_html/site** i have te result of the command : ***npm run build*** that is  the content of the folder BUILD except the *.htaccess* because i let that file in root folder to redirect all request to this folder "*site*"

but this doesn't work... i check my log file (drar.log)

`App 3970460 output: /home/designe3/public_html/site/index.html:1 App 3970460 output: <!doctype html><html lang="pt"><head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"><meta charset="UTF-8"><meta name="author" content="Bruno Rebelo"><meta name="google-site-verification" content="verification_token"/><meta name="yandex-verification" content="verification_token"/><meta name="msvalidate.01" content="verification_token"/><meta name="alexaVerifyID" content="verification_token"/><meta name="p:domain_verify" content="code_from_pinterest"/><meta name="norton-safeweb-site-verification" content="norton_code"/><meta name="robots" content="index,follow"><meta name="googlebot" content="index,follow"><meta name="google" content="nositelinkssearchbox"/><meta name="google" content="notranslate"/><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="favicon/apple-touch-icon.png"/><link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="favicon/favicon-32x32.png"/><link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="favicon/favicon-16x16.png"/><link rel="manifest" href="favicon/site.webmanifest"><link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json"/><link rel="stylesheet" charset="UTF-8" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css"/><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css"/><script defer="defer" src="./static/js/main.ed6f1117.js"></script><link href="./static/css/main.5a63c539.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id="root"></div></body></html> App 3970460 output: ^ App 3970460 output: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' App 3970460 output:     at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18) App 3970460 output:     at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:15) App 3970460 output:     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1162:27) App 3970460 output:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1252:10) App 3970460 output:     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1076:32) App 3970460 output:     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:911:12) App 3970460 output:     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1100:19) App 3970460 output:     at Module.require (/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:80:25) App 3970460 output:     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:108:18) App 3970460 output:     at loadApplication (/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:243:2)`

and i have this error : SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

in my browser i get :

`Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`

can someone help me please ?

thanks
Bruno

At this moment my package.json has homepage set to "."

```
"homepage": "."
```

i allready tried :

```
"homepage": "mydomain.com"
"homepage": "mydomain.com/site/"
```

and  im my Root folder ( **public_html** ) i have a .htaccess file with the content :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```